# eclipse ubuntu 18.04 installation java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, ubuntu-18.04

Installed eclipse and Java8. But it isn't working. 
When try to run it following error occur.

**An error has occurred. See the log file
/home/shield/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1526718159168.log**

I checked the log file and found these lines:

```
**    !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2018-05-19 13:40:07.262
   !MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
   !STACK
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)**
```

Comment: Can you please also show what is in the log before (`!SESSION`...) and after (whole stack trace with all `Caused by:`...) the snippet?

Comment: I get almost the same log file as shown above.  There is nothing prior to !SESSION and nothing afterwards either (most especially no Caused by).  The entire log file is shown above.

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of the following one on StackOverflow, where the general gist of the answer is that Ubuntu has a very old version of Eclipse which no longer is compatible with modern versions of Java in Ubuntu.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440132/eclipse-application-crashes-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just went through same issue with Ubuntu 18.04. Don't know specific answer but reinstalling directly from eclipse.org (C/C++ installer)  eclipse-cpp-oxygen-3a-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz went well. No more issues. 
Installing at Ubuntu 16.04, no issues found with synaptic installation either.
So, just use eclipse installer in newest Ubuntu.