# Eclipse application crashes on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin, trace

I am running Trace compass on Ubuntu 18.04. I installed eclipse from Ubuntu Software but when I run Trace compass I get the error log:

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=10.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-05-20 18:51:41.714
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:       javax/annotation/PostConstruct
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
```

Comment: The Ubuntu/Debian build is over 5 years out of date at this point. It predates Java 9, never mind 10. Get a newer version from download.eclipse.org.

Comment: Your Eclipse is too old to run with Java 10 - use Eclipse Oxygen.3a

Comment: @greg-449 I have Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a).

Comment: Oxygen.3a would say `eclipse.buildId=4.7.3.M20180330-0640` **not** `eclipse.buildId=unknown`

Comment: @greg-449 I installed again the latest available eclipse but same error log. Do I need to specify any environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading version 4.8 from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ here.Worked for me.