# eclipse does not start - wrong eclipse.ini?

Tags: java, eclipse

I just installed the official eclipse photon version via oomph-installer on an ubuntu-64 bit machine on a vm workstation.

Unfortunately it does not start, giving me this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I inspected the eclipse.ini and found that on startup these two files are needed:

> lugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
>   plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.dist

But they are not present in the actual plugins directory (/usr/share/eclipse/plugins). Are these files missing or are other files needed on startup?

Comment: Looks like your eclipse installation is corrupt. I suggest downloading it again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50423322/2985643

Comment: thank you. directly installing eclipse as suggested solution in this post solved my issue. Somehow i did not see this post when i searched for a solution.